# Wordpress Custom Options In Admin Area

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to create an custom option so that the user in the admin area could be able to select a alternative css that I will provide. I have made a custom page using the `add_menu_page` function in the functions.php.

How could I retrieve all the .css files contained in the directory "/css" to make it easier for the user?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good codex page on creating admin options pages:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Use `dir` to get a list of all the css files:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php

Comment: This tutorial didn't worked for me, probably because of it's old wordpress version (2.9). This one worked : http://www.tutorialstag.com/simple-wordpress-seo-plugin-using-custom-meta-final-part.html